# run function when click a button

Tags: javascript

i add this script to my page  it is a poll contain a button i want when user click on button it run a function

**JavaScript embed code:**

```
   <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="http://static.polldaddy.com/p/6061322.js"></script>
   <noscript><a href="http://polldaddy.com/poll/6061322/">أختار مرشحك للرئاسة</a></noscript>
```

Comment: Can you try to make your question more understandable? There's no real sentence here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use jquery like this:

```
$('.pds-vote-button').bind('click', function() {
  //call your function
});
```

you may want to unbind what is already happening....

Comment: Sorry, my bad, its a class...will update the answer. Meanwhile check this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/B7Xwf/

Comment: still not work , i am completely new in coding this is my function
http://jsfiddle.net/bT25A/3/

Answer (score 0):

Just substitute your function name

```
<a href="http://polldaddy.com/poll/6061322/" onclick="functioneName()">
```

Comment: inline javascript is a bad idea.

Comment: @zzzzBov: care to expand upon "bad idea", or provide a link?

Comment: @RyanS, HTML, CSS, and JS are [MVC](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7005319/497418). [Each belong in their own file](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4629752/497418).